# JavaScript Regex Remove Content from String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"cghdfgf' hgfhdfgh 'hgfhf'hghdf'gf' 'ghfdh"
```

Using a regex ( by replacing a regex with a string, eg `str.replace(/regex/g, '')`) I want to be able to strip all characters between single quotes within that string, so that it looks like this:

```
"cghdfgf''hgfhf''gf''ghfdh"
```

Is this possible with a regex?

Comment: You haven't posted what you've tried so far.

Comment: Just to be clear:  there are no characters between single quotes in your test string.

Comment: @SteveKline That's because I don't know where to start.

Comment: W3 schools, mozilla, there are literally millions of examples out there. Google is where you can start. There are hundreds of YouTube videos as well. There's a huge difference in not knowing and not trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya, you may try this.

```
string.replace(/'[^']*'/g, "''")
```

`[^']*` negated character class which matches any character but not of single quote, zero or more times.

Comment: Thanks, had no idea it was this simple.

Answer (score 1):

you may use

```
string.replace(/'.*?'/g,"''");
```

hope it helps!

below is the snippet

```js
var test="cghdfgf' hgfhdfgh 'hgfhf'hghdf'gf' 'ghfdh";

var ganti=test.replace(/'.*?'/g,"''");

alert(ganti);
```